# How to debug my code Ruby , Javascript, CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, debugging

I'm new to developing and started with a ruby on rails tutorial.
There i came to an error and after redoing it and googling it for days i can't figure it out. I was told to learn how to debug but i have no clue how to. i read that it actually is not possible to debug css. Maybe i used the wrong expression and i don't want to make it about my error which i already asked about here: [CSS is not working after push to heroku but works on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469559/css-is-not-working-after-push-to-heroku-but-works-on-localhost)

and here [endless scrolling does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471958/endless-scrolling-does-not-work)

but i was wondering how to debug in general. i found various code snippets but not a really good tutorial where it explains everything from the beginning. i found things about breakpoints which i have no clue about what it is and where to set and how to read or where to get the logfile. do you know any good tutorials about that topic which i weren't able to find yet. something like a debugging for dummies.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) site is an excellent resource for learning Rails.

Here's a great one on your subject: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html -- section 3 goes into the debugger itself. Should really be all you need, but let me know if you've any specific questions after reading this.

Debugging CSS is different, though. Generally, the best way to debug CSS is to play with it in real time in a web page. You can do this with the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) addon for FireFox, or the web inspector which is built in to Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging means finding and fixing problems with your code. You can start by checking your code for syntax errors (such as typos in function names or missing punctuation). Then use print statements (such as document.write in JavaScript) to check that your variables have the correct values. Also check for mistakes in logic, such as off-by-ones and infinite loops. Based on the unexpected results (and error message, if any), try to figure out which part of your code is faulty. You can debug without a debugger program, but they offer useful features. Your code can run slowly (line-by-line or pausing at the breakpoint), so after each line/breakpoint, you can check its status.